# How to remove a specific field from the comment form on WordPress

Tags: wordpress

How can I remove the website field from the comments form on my WordPress [site](https://houseweather.org/). I'm tired of spammers.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you have to copy this code in your theme function.php

```
add_filter('comment_form_default_fields', 'remove_website_from_comments');
function remove_website_from_comments($fields){
    if(isset($fields['url']))
       unset($fields['url']);
       return $fields;
}
```

here more information about this hook:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comment_form_default_fields/

Answer (score 1):

[Akismet](https://wordpress.org/plugins/akismet/) is your best bet against spammers.
If you want to remove it there is many ways.
**CSS** in custom CSS in Customizer

```
div.site_re.end {
    display: none;
}
```

**PHP** in functions.php of child theme otherwise will be removed on next theme update.

```
add_filter('comment_form_default_fields', 'remove_website_from_comments');
function remove_website_from_comments($fields){
    if(isset($fields['url']))
       unset($fields['url']);
       return $fields;
}
```